# How can I get the most flavor out of cashews?

Tags: flavor, nuts

I'd like to make a soup that uses cashews for much of its flavor.  For some reason, I can only use a limited number of cashews, but I can use them in any way I want.

How can I get the most cashew flavor into the soup?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By maximising first the flavour of every single nut and then maximising 
the surface:

Gently roast the cashews, then grind them finely.

If the resulting "gritty" texture is not to your taste, grind them further until you get a nut butter, which should dissolve nicely especially in cream-type soups.

Comment: Recipes for peanut butter soup seem like they could be nicely adapted to use a cashew butter!